# Searching websites using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, web-scraping

What I would like to do is to search a [website](https://pl.pons.com/t%C5%82umaczenie-tekstu) using VBA, putting some words in the left box and getting results on the right.

The problem is that I don't know HTML and I don't know how to refer to this box. I use *`GetElementByID`* but I received error in line:

> ```
> objIE.Document.GetElementByID("text-translation-video-ad").Value = "piłka".   
> "Object doesn't support this property or method".
> ```

Here's my code:

```
Sub www()

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIE.Top = 0
    objIE.Left = 0
    objIE.Width = 800
    objIE.Height = 600
    objIE.AddressBar = 0
    objIE.StatusBar = 0
    objIE.Toolbar = 0
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate ("https://pl.pons.com/tłumaczenie-tekstu")

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

    pagesource = objIE.Document.Body.Outerhtml
    objIE.Document.GetElementByID("text-translation-video-ad").Value = "piłka"
    objIE.Document.GetElementByID("qKeyboardInputInitiator").Click

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by "search websites"? Do you want to search a page's HTML for specific words, or do you want to search across multiple pages?

Answer (score 4):

Without changing any language settings, the following translates "Hello"

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument, translation As String
    Const TRANSLATION_STRING As String = "Hello"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://pl.pons.com/t%C5%82umaczenie-tekstu"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = .document

        With html
            .querySelector("textarea.text-translation-source.source").Value = TRANSLATION_STRING
            .querySelector("button.btn.btn-primary.submit").Click
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
            translation = .querySelector("div.translated_text").innerText
        End With

        Debug.Print translation
        'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With

End Sub
```

**View:**

[image: Output]

**Print out in immediate window:**

[image: Output]

---

**Edit:**

Late bound version

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As Object, html As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://pl.pons.com/t%C5%82umaczenie-tekstu"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set html = .document

        With html

            .getElementsByClassName("text-translation-source source")(0).innerText = "Translate"
            .getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary submit")(0).Click
             Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

             Dim i As Long
             For i = 0 To .getElementsByClassName("text-translation-target target").Length - 1
                 Debug.Print .getElementsByClassName("text-translation-target target")(i).innerText
             Next i

            Stop
        End With
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Element with ID "text-translation-video-ad" is a DIV which does not have `.Value` property. You want to access text area which is descendant of mentioned DIV.

There are 2 elements with tag "textarea" on page, the one which interests you is 1st element, therefore (0) index. Tags in `GetElementsByTagName` must be capitalized.

```
objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA")(0).Value = "piłka"
```

You can also resign from IE automation and take a faster and more reliable approach, without browser automation, which will give you response in JSON format. Setting reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library is required.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Scrape()

    Dim WindHttp As Object: Set WindHttp = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    Dim htmlDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim urlName As String, myWord As String, requestString As String
    Dim myResults() As String
    Dim resultNum As Long

    urlName = "https://pl.pons.com/_translate/translate"
    myWord = "piłka"

    requestString = "source_language=pl&target_language=en&service=deepl&text=" & _
    myWord & _
    "&lookup=true&requested_by=Web&source_language_confirmed=true"

    Set htmlDoc = postDocument(urlName, WindHttp, requestString)

    myResults = Split(Replace(Split(Split(htmlDoc.body.innerText, ",")(1), ":")(1), Chr(34), vbNullString), vbCrLf)

    For resultNum = LBound(myResults) To UBound(myResults)
        Debug.Print myResults(resultNum)
    Next resultNum

End Sub

Function postDocument(ByVal urlName As String, myRequest As Object, Optional requestString As String) As HTMLDocument

    Set postDocument = New HTMLDocument

    With myRequest

        .Open "POST", urlName, False
        .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
        .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        If requestString = vbNullString Then
            .send
        Else
            .send requestString
        End If

        postDocument.body.innerHTML = .responseText

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Great!, in the same way I've tried to click button "Przetłumacz" but it doesn't work. (    objIE.Document.GetElementByTagName("BUTTON")(5).Click)

Comment: It's "Elements" in method name and index of 5th element is 4, because enumeration starts from 0. Use: `objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON")(4).Click`

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with "Element" instead of "Elements". Now I try to change language from default English to Polish. Can I also use "GetElementsByTagName"? I've tried objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON")(0).Value = "polskiego" but it neither returns an error nor changes language.

Comment: It's rather a material for another post, but this button doesn't have any value. Span element inside it has. Also you can change this text in span manually in browser and then click a button to translate and see what happens - website doesn't care about value being changed. You must click on dropdown list <a> element.

Comment: Well, to be honest I don't know how it should look like. I've tried several times but I've received either an error or no result.