# Changing span element on the website - VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I need to change span element on the website, I mean I have to change a language on the pons website. Here's my code:

```vb
Sub www()

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIE.Top = 0
    objIE.Left = 0
    objIE.Width = 800
    objIE.Height = 600
    objIE.AddressBar = 0
    objIE.StatusBar = 0
    objIE.Toolbar = 0
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate ("https://pl.pons.com/tłumaczenie-tekstu")

    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
    pagesource = objIE.Document.Body.Outerhtml
    objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA")(0).Value = "piłka"
    objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON")(5).Click

    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line with my earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50599203/6241235) to this here is how you change the languages.

**Note:**

Late binding won't offer you the interface for `.querySelector`. It has to be with early binding i.e. reference added for `HTML Object Library`.

Additional reference is `Microsoft Internet Controls` though this doesn't affect `.querySelector`.

---

To do from and to languages use:

```
.querySelectorAll("button span")(0).innerText = "bulgarski" '<== To
.querySelectorAll("button span")(1).innerText = "arabskiego" '<== From
```

Or more targeted:

```
.querySelectorAll("button[class = ""btn dropdown-toggle""]")(0).innerText = "chinskiego"
.querySelectorAll("button[class = ""btn dropdown-toggle""]")(1).innerText = "bulgarski"
```

Or even:

```
.querySelectorAll("button.btn.dropdown-toggle span")(0).innerText = "chinskiego"
.querySelectorAll("button.btn.dropdown-toggle span")(1).innerText = "arabskiego"
```

---

The methods above use CSS selectors i.e. that make use of the page styling to select the items of interest.

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` of all nodes matching the specified CSS selector. The `NodeList` items are then accessed by index e.g. 0, 1.

---

CSS Selectors:

1. [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
2. [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument, translation As String
    Const TRANSLATION_STRING As String = "Hello"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://pl.pons.com/t%C5%82umaczenie-tekstu"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = .document

        With html

            .querySelectorAll("button span")(0).innerText = "polskiego"
            .querySelectorAll("button span")(1).innerText = "angielskiego"

'            .querySelectorAll("button[class = ""btn dropdown-toggle""]")(0).innerText = "chinskiego"
'            .querySelectorAll("button[class = ""btn dropdown-toggle""]")(1).innerText = "bulgarski"
'
'            .querySelectorAll("button span")(0).innerText = "chinskiego"
'            .querySelectorAll("button span")(1).innerText = "chinskiego"
''
'            .querySelectorAll("button.btn.dropdown-toggle span")(0).innerText = "chinskiego"
'            .querySelectorAll("button.btn.dropdown-toggle span")(1).innerText = "arabskiego"

Stop

            .querySelector("textarea.text-translation-source.source").Value = TRANSLATION_STRING
            .querySelector("button.btn.btn-primary.submit").Click
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
            translation = .querySelector("div.translated_text").innerText
        End With

        Debug.Print translation
        'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With

End Sub
```

---

**Example run:**

[image: Test run]

---

**Edit:**

This is not robust but you may be able to do, for late binding with HTML file

```
.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText = "chinskiego"  '<== from
.getElementsByTagName("span")(26).innerText = "bulgarski" '<== to
```

**Late bound:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As Object, html As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://pl.pons.com/t%C5%82umaczenie-tekstu"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set html = .document

        With html

            .getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText = "chinskiego"
            .getElementsByTagName("span")(26).innerText = "bulgarski"

            Stop
        End With
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

---

Don't really want this answer to go on forever (so apologies for current length)... In response to OPs later question regarding sometimes values not held in late bound translation.

Please see more **fragile** version. In the version below I have first looped all the span elements and found out which index relates to which language selection and in which box:

Mini guide to spans:

[image: span elements with index]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As Object, html As Object, translation As String

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://pl.pons.com/t%C5%82umaczenie-tekstu"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set html = .document

        Dim i As Long
        'Dim listOfSpanElements As Worksheet
        'Set listOfSpanElements = Worksheets.Add

'        With listOfSpanElements ''<== This was used to ascertain position of all the span elements and hence which span to click on to select a language.
'
'            For i = 0 To html.getElementsByTagName("span").Length - 1
'                Cells(i + 1, 1) = html.getElementsByTagName("span")(i).innerText
'            Next i
'
'        End With


        With html

            .getElementsByTagName("button")(1).Focus
            .getElementsByTagName("button")(1).Click
            .getElementsByClassName("text-translation-source source")(0).innerText = "Sponsorowane"
            .getElementsByTagName("span")(15).Click 'FROM polskiego
            .getElementsByTagName("span")(47).Click 'TO angielski
            .getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary submit")(0).Click
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4)
           Stop

            For i = 0 To .getElementsByClassName("text-translation-target target").Length - 1
               Debug.Print .getElementsByClassName("text-translation-target target")(i).innerText '<==later remove "Trwa ladowanie..."
            Next i
        End With
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This line : .querySelector("button span").innerText = "polskiego" works but I want to choose language from and to so when I use these: .querySelectorAll("button span")(0).innerText = "polskiego"
.querySelectorAll("button span")(1).innerText = "angielskiego" I received an error "Automation error"

Comment: It works fine my end.  Can you tell me a bit more about the error?

Comment: That's ok. We are here to help. Please feel free to ask questions. QuerySelector is for IE9+ I think.

Comment: Well, I don't understand this syntax. I've been studying VBA for a couple of months but I don't know HTML at all. Now I get an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: What version of IE are you running?

Comment: I think that the problem is that I use late binding. So I wrote:  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") and it's OK but I don't know how to create HTML object. I wrote:  Set html = CreateObject("HTMLDocument") but I got an error: ActiveX component can't create object.

Comment: Are you allowed to add the reference to HTML Object library?

Comment: Well, I have to use late binding because I don't know the version of Excel on computer on which my application will be used. How can I chage that?

Comment: No, I'm not allowed.

Comment: You are amazing! It works! I don't know this site very well but I'd like to thank You as much as I can.

Comment: I have updated your other question with a late bound as well.

Comment: It's strange, I use your code (late binding) and I want to translate sth from Polish to English but it seems to me that "Przetłumacz" (translate) button doesn't work. Instead website is refreshed and languages from and to are changed for Arabic and German.

Comment: Well, I had to change website for https://pl.pons.com/t%C5%82umaczenie, I changed my code but I need to refer to the first field of translated word.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Can you do a https://pastebin.com/ of your code so I can run it. And can you include in the pastebin the expected output.

Comment: I have done a new edit at the bottom of the question for you to try.

Comment: I have updated my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598496/searching-websites-using-vba/50599043#50599043 It now also contains processing of JSON response on this particular website.

Comment: hello @RyszardJędraszyk ! :-)

Comment: @QHarr I have just pasted my code on pastebin.com, my login: ArkadiuszWarsaw

Comment: Cool. Please also try the latest edit. You also need to share the link that is generated from pastebin.com